# Fetching the record with the "earliest" time per employee ID

Tags: sql-server, function

SQL Server 2008 R2:

I Need to return all field values of a record and cannot find a solution.

In a table there are scheduled working times of employees (EmplID). During the shift he starts in a certain Team (Team), with a certain teamleader (SV) and many other fields, all in connection to the first assignment, and this record has the earliest time (Startime). Later his shift he changes to another Team, of course with a later time and different teamleader and so on. Every record has a unique ID and a timestamp field. Assignments have not been done cronolocical ascending.

I can fetch the first time with MIN(startime) but I cannot get all the other fields of the record with the first time.

I made scalar functions for the 3 fields but I have about 20 fields and I doubt that there is no other way to fetch the whole record based on the "earliest time".

Thanks your help
Michael

Comment: TOP 1 ORDER BY StartTime?   Is there some reason it's not that simple?

Comment: Look into `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID, Team, SV ORDER BY StartTime ASC) ` and select record `where row_number = 1`

Comment: @TabAlleman the question states `Ealiest time per employee` top 1 will return the earliest time across all employees.

Comment: share with us the data structure and the sql code you already wrote: that will make easier for us to help you.

Comment: @M.Ali You see the words "earliest time per employee" in the question?   I must be missing it.   I DO see the words "I Need to return all field values of a record" and note that "record" is singular.

Comment: @M.Ali ah, it's in the subject, I wasn't looking there.  The question is unclear, but I think he only needs a single row returned, not one row for every employee.  If he only needs a single row, then `TOP 1 ... WHERE EmployeeID = xxx ... ORDER BY StartTime` would do the trick.

Comment: @M.Ali you are right but OP needs 1 record per employee so partition by `EmpID` only.  `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY StartTime ASC)`

Comment: Thanks M. Ali, I found my solution on Row_number() OVER Partition...

It took some time to understand how it works but finaly I got my query done.